# Primary Key (Database First) using entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework, client-server

I have 2 tables. They were created in MySQL, then the Database first method was applied (This means that all the primary keys and navigation properties were set by the Entity Framework itself when importing the database from MySQL in VS). These two tables are connected(one-to-many) by a primary key (Id_Cus).
1st table

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class customer
    {
        public customer()
        {
            this.dishesrankings = new HashSet<dishesranking>();
            this.orders = new HashSet<order>();
        }

        public int Id_Cus { get; set; }
        public string FirstName_Cus { get; set; }
        public string LastName_Cus { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNum_Cus { get; set; }
        public string Email_Cus { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<dishesranking> dishesrankings { get; set; }
        public virtual customerpreference customerpreference { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<order> orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2nd table

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class customerpreference
    {
        public int Id_Cus { get; set; }
        public int Id_Res { get; set; }
        public string Name_Dis { get; set; }
        public int Id_Type { get; set; }

        public virtual customer customer { get; set; }
        public virtual order order { get; set; }
        public virtual type_dishes type_dishes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here I fill in the first table, everything works correctly and the first table is filled.

```
public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
        {
            //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities();
            customer cust = new customer();
            {
                cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
                cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
                cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
                cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
            };
            dc.customers.Add(cust);
            dc.SaveChanges();
```

Next up is the problem. The first table is full, but no values ​​are placed in the second table in the Id_Cus field. As I understand it, since the tables are interconnected, I want the Id_Cus field in the second table also to be populated when this field is filled in the first table.
I tried as shown in the code below, but did not succeed, could you give some recommendations?

```
 public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
        {
            //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities();
            customer cust = new customer();
            {
                cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
                cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
                cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
                cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
            };
            dc.customers.Add(cust);


            customerpreference custPref = new customerpreference()
            {
                Id_Cus = customerDataContract.Id_Cus,
                Id_Res = 0, // some value
                Name_Dis = null, // some value
                Id_Type = 0 // some value
            };
            dc.customerpreferences.Add(custPref);

            dc.SaveChanges();

            int k = Convert.ToInt32(cust.Id_Cus);
            customer custFromDb =(from n in dc.customers
                                  where n.Id_Cus == k
                                  select n).Include(c => c.customerpreference).First();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to better name your variables and column names, they are quite confusing.

It is not clear what are primary keys and what is foreign keys in the `customerpreference` class. I think the main issue is that you are trying to insert a foreign key of the child objest before the parent exists in the database

```
customer cust = new customer();
        {
            cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
            cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
            cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
            cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
            cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
            cust.customerpreference = new customerpreference()
             {
                Id_Res = 0, // some value
                Name_Dis = null, // some value
                Id_Type = 0 // some value
             };
        };
        dc.customers.Add(cust);
        dc.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: It doesn't work 
exception: "System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'
"

Comment: @КириллФилободченко, expand the entity errors and see what information is missing